# How to access data from a JSON API ?

Tags: json, api, web

I'm trying to use the New York City Bus API in order to create an app. The last API I worked with, was while learning Python. I have no idea where to begin.

This is the link to the documentation
http://bustime.mta.info/wiki/Developers/SIRIIntro

If you guys could point me towards how I can get the data from the API. I already got the Key.

Thank You so Much

Comment: Does the documentation not describe how to use it?

Comment: I tried reading it. I understood as far as they are using Json for the format and using a REST API. But idk how to fetch the data

Comment: You just use one of the urls they listed.

Comment: But where? And how Like included on the JavaScript. Such as link + key ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use requests to fetch data from api.

```
import requests    
url  = "http://api.prod.obanyc.com/api/siri/vehicle-monitoring.json?key={}".format(key)

# fetch data 
data = requests.get(url).json()

# do something with data.
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to implement this ok a website. Could this be done with JavaScript ?

Comment: I Googled 'javascript make rest call' and found everything you would need. Please show some effort by reading and attempting.